# Gridview binding details

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I got a combobox that I bind to database and when I select a order from combobox, it must display order details and customer details on seperate gridviews. I achieved that, now I want to have an "All" option in that combobox when ALL is selected it display all order details and customer details from database.

Note I got tables which are `ordersDetails` and `customerDetails` they have foreign key to the `Orders` table. I retrieve data using a foreign key but now option ALL doesnt have foreign key thats the problem that I am facing. I have bound my gridviews with a datasource.

My code for select combobox binding

```
SELECT 
    [ID], [orderName], 
FROM 
    Orders
```

My gridview select code that display selected item on gridview according to what is selected from combobox

```
SELECT 
    CustomerName, CustomerName,
FROM 
    Orders 
INNER JOIN
    OrderDetails ON Orders.ID = OrderDetails.OrderRef
WHERE 
    ID = @.orderRef
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all the details and all the order details, from the database you'd need to change your query

Call the following function on your `DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged`

```
protected void GetOrders(int OrderID = 0)
{
// Connection objects defined here

// Get the order details
if (OrderID == 0) {
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM OrderDetails";
} else {
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderID = " + OrderID;
}

DataSet ds = null;
SqlDataAdapter da = new default(SqlDataAdapter);
// check this, it might be a SqlTableAdapter

da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(System.Data.sql, conn);
da.Fill(ds);

gvOrderDetails.DataSource = ds;
gvOrderDetails.DataBind();
}
```

This just gets the data for one of your Gridviews (in a DataSet so you can page the GridViews if you need to).

You can copy this procedure to get the CustomerDetails too.

The code above assumes that you have a value of 0 set to your ALL item in the DropDownList.

So if your DropDownList is called ddlOrders, call the procedure as follows:

```
protected void ddlOrders_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
GetOrders(ddlOrders.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

The same with GetCustomers.

These will populate the GridViews with rows that match a specific OrderID or all orders.

Hope this helps

Comment: da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(System.Data.sql, conn); says Object reference not set to an instance of an object but i do have data on database and there is a link

Comment: sorry about that, declare the data adapter as `new`. I'll revise the code